# why do i get a list error using the glm function

Tags: r

im trying to use glm like so: `model<- glm(y~radius + symmetry, data = train)`
where radius and symmetry are numeric vectors and i receive the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ radius + symmetry, data = train,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'y'
```

using `str(train$radius)` i received the following:

```
 num [1:469] 19.21 13.15 14.86 19 8.73 ...
```

using `str(train$symmetry)` i received the following:

```
 num [1:469] 0.192 0.182 0.157 0.195 0.165 ...
```

y is expecting two vectors and is getting them. then why do i have an error?

Comment: Do you have a variable named `y` in your data.frame `train`? What does `str(data$y)` return? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: sorry.this is my first time publishing a question and therefore i haven't mastered the craft yet. i havent got a variable named y in my data and str(data$y) returns NULL. its a bit difficult to include an example since this might be specific to the data im using or in general with the glm function and i really don't know how to address the problem. i have read many examples on line but not managing to solve the problem.

Comment: Then the formula you are passing to glm doesn’t make sense. In your modeling what are your dependent and independent variables? What are you trying to predict or model?

Comment: I was really stupid. The formula wasn't right and I needed to put it in as factor